# How can I make Http get request using Volley on this JSON format

Tags: android, http, get, android-volley

IMPORTANT: All ids and keys are to be ignored. They are autogenerated. For each row only the value attribute is relevant for
you.

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"0342fde43316bffdea32d0ec990dba4e","key":"0342fde43316bffdea32d0ec990dba4e","value":{"title":"My Idea","content":"I have to discuss my idea with the team"}},
{"id":"0342fde43316bffdea32d0ec990ee122","key":"0342fde43316bffdea32d0ec990ee122","value":{"title":"New project","content":"I need to call the customer"}},
{"id":"0342fde43316bffdea32d0ec990f168c","key":"0342fde43316bffdea32d0ec990f168c","value":{"title":"Birth day","content":"Buy a gift for my mom!"}}

]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use from this [link](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)

```
final String URL = "/volley/resource/12";
// Post params to be sent to the server
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("token", "AbCdEfGh123456");

JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
       new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               try {
                   VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
           }
       });

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```